# Connection Exception while running Sqoop from Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, sqoop

I am currently trying to run a Sqoop Import job which is part of a Spark JAR.

I am using `com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions` and `com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool` to run the Sqoop Job.

Code looks something like this:

```
import com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions
import com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool

val options = new SqoopOptions
val sqoopImport  = new ImportTool

options.setConnectString("..")
options.setTargetDir("..")

//and a bunch of other Sqoop related options

//and finally 
val ret = sqoopImport.run(options)
```

But his doesn't run at all. The job stays in `RUNNING` for multiple hours and fails with a `ConnectionException`

> Failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

The compiler also gives warnings that `SqoopOptions` and `ImportTool` are deprecated.

I can execute the code perfectly from `spark-shell`

I am submitting my application with `--master yarn-cluster --deploy-mode cluster`

Any idea what is going wrong here? Is there a different API that I must be using?

Comment: is there connectivity opened between datanodes and DB nodes?

Comment: Are you using the `--jars` to broadcast the jars to the cluster?

Comment: @squid it's a 60 node cluster so I'm not really sure. And yes, I am providing all the JARs. This doesn't look like a missing JAR issue though.

Comment: sqoop jobs internally launch mapreduce/spark job to perform operations( read/write), sqoop job connect to database server in distributed mode to perform any operations, so there should be connectivity opened between your datanodes and DB servers. In most cases all datanodes in cluster belongs to same subnet and if one node is able to connect then rest nodes also will do. From spark/hive job run telnet command and see the connectivity is open.